# How can I condition a button click not to execute, if the click is not immediately released in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

What I want the **button** not to do is that the linked function is executed if the user holds the click and when he releases it the function does not execute, because I have an `event` linked to the **button** `bind` to **move the window** as it doesn't have the **window manager** and the app is mostly just buttons. Thank you very much for all the help you can give me.

```
from tkinter import *

def destroy1():
    print('Hellow')

root = Tk()
frm = Frame(root, bg='gray')
frm.pack()
btn = Button(frm, text='Closed', command= destroy1)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: First remove `command` option for `btn`. Then time the period between button press and release (via bindings on `<ButtonPress-1>` and `<ButtonRelease-1>` on `btn`), if the period is shorter than a certain time, call `destroy1()` in the button release callback.

Comment: Thanks for asking, I want the function linked to the button not to be executed if the user holds the button down for more than 2 seconds, only that.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I'll try to do what **acw1668** suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that can be done easily, but if you really want to do it:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

FLAG = None

def on_press(x):
    global FLAG
    FLAG = time.time()

def on_release(x):
    if FLAG is None: return
    if time.time() - FLAG > 2: root.destroy()
    FLAG = None


root = Tk()

frm = Frame(root, bg='gray')
frm.pack()
btn = Button(frm, text='Closed')
btn.pack()

btn.bind('<ButtonPress>', on_press)
btn.bind('<ButtonRelease>', on_release)

root.mainloop()
```

destroys only if the button is hold for > 2 seconds

Comment: You're very welcome.